# Trouble importing Numpy into Grass GIS 7.0 on Windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, module, anaconda, grass

I recently installed Grass GIS 7 on my Windows 10. Upon loading the program, I receive an error in the terminal window stating:

> 'This module requires the Numeric/numarray or NumPy module, which
> could not be imported. It probably is not installed (it's part of the
> standard Python distribution). See the Numeric Python site
> ([Link](https://numpy.org)) for information on Numeric, numarray, or
> NumPy not found'.

I installed Anaconda separately which contains the NumPy module, but it is not being recognized by Grass GIS. How do I have Grass recognize this module is already installed on my computer?

I have Windows 10, and both Anaconda and Grass were downloaded as 64-bit. Anaconda downloaded with Python 3.5 and Grass was downloaded with OSGeo64W 7.0.4 version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that GRASS brings its own Python interpreter with it rather than using the Anaconda version that you installed. As the [notes on GRASS and Python](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python#Using_a_version_of_Python_different_from_the_default_installation) remark "On Windows, Python scripts are invoked via `%GRASS_PYTHON%`, so changing that environment variable will change the interpreter." If you set the `GRASS_PYTHON` environment variable to point to the Anaconda Python binary you may find things start to work better.

Comment: How do I go about setting the GRASS_PYTHON environment variable? And, how do I find the Anaconda Python binary location on my computer? I am brand new to Python and Grass.

Comment: IIRC in Windows you would use a command like `set GRASS_PYTHON=C:\path\to\Python\interpreter` to set the environment variable. You can [add it to your system settings](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) too.

You installed Anaconda. Sorry, I have no idea where you put it!

Answer (score 0):

In OSGeo4W installer, upgrading python-numpy to 1.11.0-1 caused this error in GRASS 7.0.4 for me. Backing python-numpy to 2.7-1.7.0-1 solved the Problem